# Removing the backslash from a literal notation of a regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to create a regex from user input string. This is my code. I have input with id 'regex'.

```
<input id='regex'/>
```

And this is my js code.

```
var regex = $('#regex').val();
regexp = new RegExp(regex);

testString = "foo is bar";

alert(testString.replace(regexp, ''));
```

But if I add **/ /g** as an example to remove spaces from a string it's not working. And I get this as regexp

```
/\/ \/g/
```

is there a way to convert this to exactly like my string as regex?

Comment: The [`RegExp` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Syntax) accepts its flags as the second argument. You'd need to parse them out of the input string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the user puts `/` on each side of the pattern, followed by word characters and the end of the string on the right, parse them out before passing to `new RegExp`, and pass the word characters as the second argument:

```js
$('#regex').on('change', () => {
  const input = $('#regex').val();
  const match = input.match(/^\/(.*)\/(\w+)$/);
  const pattern = match
    ? new RegExp(match[1], match[2])
    : new RegExp(input);
  console.log(pattern);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='regex'/>
```